# Handling mouse for first person game in monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I am trying to make a first-person game on Monogame and so far all I have come with or found on the internet didn't meet my standards. 
this is how I am currently handling the mouse:

```
        private void HandleMouse()
        {
            Vector2 mouseDifference;
            mouseNow = Mouse.GetState();
            if (mouseNow.X != mouseDefaultPos.X || mouseNow.Y != mouseDefaultPos.Y)
            {
                mouseDifference.X = mouseDefaultPos.X - mouseNow.X;
                mouseDifference.Y = mouseDefaultPos.Y - mouseNow.Y;
                leftrightRot += mouseSens * mouseDifference.X;
                updownRot += mouseSens * mouseDifference.Y;

                Mouse.SetPosition((int)mouseDefaultPos.X, (int)mouseDefaultPos.Y);

                UpdateViewMatrix();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateViewMatrix()
        {
            Matrix cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(updownRot) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(leftrightRot);

            Vector3 cameraOriginalTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
            Vector3 cameraOriginalUpVector = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

            Vector3 cameraRotatedTarget = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalTarget, cameraRotation);

            Vector3 cameraRotatedUpVector = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalUpVector, cameraRotation);


            viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0,0,0), cameraRotatedTarget, cameraRotatedUpVector);
        }
```

My problem is that while this solution works, it is extremely inconsistent when it comes to how far the camera should rotate.
for example, happens when I make circles with the mouse and see that sometimes the mouse randomly jumps more than expected. 
My main assumptions inconsistencies in fps that cause the time between frames to change, thus affecting the distance the mouse can move within that time.

I don't know if this is the reason or if my assumption can even cause this, but I would like to find a way to get consistent mouse movement.

I can provide a video of the problem if needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse in Windows is updated 240 times per second.  The game loop runs at 60 frames per second.  The discrepancy can lead to large mouse deltas.  The solution is to limit the change in the mouse delta:

```
Vector2 mouseDifference;
const float MAXDELTA = 6; // Set to the appropriate value.
mouseNow = Mouse.GetState();
if (mouseNow.X != mouseDefaultPos.X || mouseNow.Y != mouseDefaultPos.Y)
{
    mouseDifference.X = Math.Min(MAXDELTA, mouseDefaultPos.X - mouseNow.X);
    mouseDifference.Y = Math.Min(MAXDELTA, mouseDefaultPos.Y - mouseNow.Y);
    leftrightRot += mouseSens * mouseDifference.X;
    updownRot += mouseSens * mouseDifference.Y;

    Mouse.SetPosition((int)mouseDefaultPos.X, (int)mouseDefaultPos.Y);

    UpdateViewMatrix();
}
```

Comment: I feel like setting a limit mouse delta is just fixing one problem by making another, I believe that making a max mouse delta will also be a problem when moving the mouse rapidly, this time instead of rotating more than it should, it would rotate less than it should.

Comment: @Aofekiko, The only other method I know to do this is to hook the the underlying OS and provide a callback function in your code.  This is not thread safe, not portable and may be flagged by anti-virus software.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I figured I would share a solution.  The solution that's worked for me to use the GameTime object to relate how much the player should rotate by. In other words, rotate by (delta * rotationSpeed * GameTime.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds) so that each rotation is relative to how much time has passed since the last frame.  This protects it against frame drops, which I've found has been the problem for me.